# Store multiple datatypes of the same parent in arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a class A which is a parent class. Then I have an unknown set of classes (let us call them B, C, D etc.) which are all child classes of A. As a common variable all Objects of A have the int variable price defined as a parameter.
In another class I need to write a code that accesses instances of B, C, D etc. which are specified by the User. The code manipulates, reads and otherwise works with these objects in order to display them in a JTable later.
I started by defining the arraylist in the scope:

```
ArrayList<A> theArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
int wealth = (some code that defines the int);
```

later I run the following code in the constructor:

```
while (this.theArrayList.size() == 0) {
  int i = 0;
  while (this.theArrayList.toArray().length > i) {
       for (A a : this.theArrayList) {
          if (a.price > this.wealth) {
              this.anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBlock.add(a);
          }

          int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * 
              this.anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBlock.toArray().length);
          if (this.anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBlock.size() == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Array length is 0!");
          }
         //Error source
         this.thisArrayList.add(this.anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBlock.get(randomIndex)); 
     }
   i++;
}
```

both theArrayList and anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBlock are defined with the same format:

```
//in the scope of the class:
ArrayList<A> theArrayList;
ArrayList<A> anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBlock;

//later in the constructor: 
this.theArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
this.anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBlock = new ArrayList<>();
```

The problem I encounter is that every time I run this code, I get "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0, Size 0" in the marked line.
If I interpret that correctly, this.thisArrayList is always size 0. I initialize it, but yet it stays empty. I added the condition in the first line of the second code block, but it results in an infinite loop rather than a solution. Since random chance is involved I thought I was unlucky and the arraylist just was always empty.
But since it cannot be filled at all, impossible, I found it might be because of incompatible datatypes in the arraylist. Since I made the code to operate with As and not with children of A, there might be a problem.
I am not sure how to further approach the problem. Somehow I need to store an unknown number of Objects of an unknown number of datatypes in an Arraylist. I would use a regular Array but the Arraylist is of unknown and possibly changing size.
But I still need it to display the data in a JTable later on.

As requested let me explain what the code is supposed to do:
As I said I have a number of subclasses from A. And the program creates an unknown number of objects of these subclasses. The goal of this code block is to check each A and take its price to check if it is greater than this.wealth. The object I use this method on has wealth and the wealth is an int defined above.
If this is done the object is added to the arraylist in line 6 of the code above. Then I do something else with the elements in that array in a random order to avoid bias. That is why I take a random index. For safty reasons and to not loose the data when another iteration of this loop occurs, I add all the elements that are chosen to a new Arraylist.
This arraylist will, once the code finished completely then be displayed using a JTable.

Comment: Check the size of `anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBlock`. If your using an ide use a famours tool called Debugger.

Comment: Didn't I do that with the while loop? I checked it several times under different conditions. If the loop is implemented, it loops continuously. if not, I get the error.

Comment: The outer loop runs if `theArrayList.size == 0`.  The inner loop runs if `theArrayList.size > i` (size is already established as 0 and `i` is initialized to 0 so the loops ends immediately).    This should never do anything... The exception message is clear - you are trying to access element 0 in a List that empty (i.e. no elements so nothing at 0).  I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with these loops - can you explain in natural language or pseudocode what this block is trying to do?  Is `thisArrayList` supposed to be `theArrayList`?

Comment: I added a paragraph explaining what the code does.

Comment: @GalliadII as far as I understand your code you don't check the size of anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBloc, what ever it is... The get method is called outside from previous if condition.

Comment: @Reporter I actually had a typo in the code from transscribing it to StackOverflow. My appolozies. I fixed it. It now repesents the actual code, I wanted to submit.
I do checkthe size of anArrayListOfAFromPreviousCodeBlock. I do so in the last if statement.

Comment: Why do you not use the debug tool of you ide?

Comment: *"I actually had a typo in the code from transscribing it to StackOverflow."* Copy/pasting a [mre] sidesteps that problem.